# PHP: indent file with blocks delimited by { and }

Tags: php, regex, indentation

How to quicky indent a string with blocks identified by `{`and `}`?

The blocks can be deeply nested.

Example-Input:

```
a
b { c { d e 
} f }
```

should result in:

```
a 
b {
    c {
        d e
    }
    f
}
```

I tried with iterative and recursive approaches but did not succeed. Regex doesnt work either.

Maybe there is a way to use PHP builtins as `print_r` oder `json_decode`after clever aubstituting `{` and `{` but I did no succeed either.

Comment: Please show a realistic example of string.

Comment: Can you share with us your attempts?

Comment: @Zoldszemesostoros: I don't really have an idea on how to start.

Comment: But you said you'd tried iterative and recursive approaches? Can we see those?

Comment: Are you trying to beautify code? I think using stack is useful.

Comment: My use case is to beautify a Lilypond file which heavily uses ``````{ and ```}```.

Comment: @iainn Please see my answer to get a idea where I got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one toplevel block in `$content` and not multiple toplevel blocks here is a possible solution:

```
function indentBlock($content,$depth=0)
{

    // function to build indent-spaces
    $indent = function($depth) {
        return str_pad("",$depth*self::INDENT," ");
    };

    // preg_match() splits $content in three parts:
    // <before> { <inbetween> } <after>
    if (preg_match('/^([^{]*){(.*)}([^}]*)$/',$content,$matches)) {

        // re-assemble $content with newlines
        $content = 
            $indent($depth).trim($matches[1])." {\n".

            // recurse for 
            $indent($depth+1).trim(self:: indentBlock($matches[2],$depth+1))."\n".
            $indent($depth)."}\n".
            $indent($depth).trim($matches[3]);
    }
    return $content;
}
```

For multiple blocks in `$content` we have to process them with a seperate loop subsequently.

The sample input

```
a
b { c { d e 
} f }
```

is processed to:

```
a
b {
  c {
    d e
  }
  f
}
```